# NHibernate query on column in related table

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have 2 classes, `Log` and `UserProfile`.  `Log` has zero or one references to `UserProfile`.

I am trying to implement a filter for searching my logs.  Currently it looks like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Searches the logs for matching records
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fromUTC">Start point timestamp of the search</param>
    /// <param name="toUTC">End point timestamp of the search</param>
    /// <param name="ofSeverity">Severity level of the log entry</param>
    /// <param name="orHigher">Retrieve more severe log entries as well that match</param>
    /// <param name="sourceStartsWith">The source field starts with these characters</param>
    /// <param name="usernameStartsWith">The username field starts with these characters</param>
    /// <param name="maxRecords">The maximum number of records to return</param>
    /// <returns>A list of Log objects with attached UserProfile objects</returns>
    public IEnumerable<Log> SearchLogs(
        DateTime fromUTC,
        DateTime toUTC,
        string ofSeverity,
        bool orHigher,
        string sourceStartsWith,
        string usernameStartsWith,
        int maxRecords)
    {
        ofSeverity = ofSeverity ?? "INFO";

        var query = DetachedCriteria.For<Log>()
            .SetFetchMode("UserProfile", NHibernate.FetchMode.Eager)
            .Add(Restrictions.In("Severity", (orHigher ?
                Translator.SeverityOrHigher(ofSeverity) : Translator.Severity(ofSeverity)).ToArray()))
            .Add(Restrictions.Between("TimeStamp", fromUTC, toUTC))
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("TimeStamp"))
            .SetMaxResults(maxRecords);

        if ((sourceStartsWith ?? string.Empty).Length > 0)
        {
            query
                .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("Source", sourceStartsWith, MatchMode.Start));
        }

        if ((usernameStartsWith ?? string.Empty).Length > 0)
        {
            query
                .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("UserProfile.UserName",
                    usernameStartsWith, MatchMode.Start));
        }

        return query.GetExecutableCriteria(_Session).List<Log>();
    }
```

...and this works fine as long as I do not specify a `usernameStartsWith` value.

If I do specify a `usernameStartsWith` value, I get a lovely yellow screen of death saying:

```
could not resolve property: UserProfile.UserName of: C3.DataModel.Log
```

I have tried every permutation I can think of to get this to work and I can't.  Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you've tried a few things already, but have you tried joining to UserProfiles using a call to `CreateCriteria` instead of `SetFetchMode`? Maybe something like this:

```
    if ((usernameStartsWith ?? string.Empty).Length > 0)
    {
        query.CreateCriteria("UserProfile")
             .Add(Restrictions.InsensitiveLike("UserName",
                usernameStartsWith, MatchMode.Start));
    }
```

Comment: To what end?  I'm trying to get back Log records that are associated with a UserProfile, not UserProfile records.

Comment: I understand that you after the Log records and not UserProfile records.  Have you at least tried what I've suggested?  I've seen the same error while working with Nhibernate, and I believe it's related to an incorrect join.

Comment: Ha, I can assure you, you're doubt is not misplaced! I wish I could explain, with certainty, the difference between `SetFetchMode` and `CreateCriteria`.  I **think** `SetFetchMode` is using a LEFT OUTER JOIN while `CreateCriteria` is using an INNER JOIN. Anyway, I'm just glad it resolved your issue.